# Python delocate-wheel breaks wheel on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, dylib, python-wheel

I'm generating wheel files to support a python distribution on MacOS using [delocate](https://github.com/matthew-brett/delocate). The wheels rely on libraries installed when gcc is installed using Homebrew.

```sh
brew install -v gcc@10
```

- `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_3/lib/gcc/10/libstdc++.6.dylib`
- `/usr/local/lib/gcc/10/libgcc_s.1.dylib`

When running `delocate-wheel` with verbose option, the above are the two libraries included in the wheel.

If I use pip to install the original wheel, I can run the program without issue.

After running delicate-wheel and installing the new de-located wheel and trying to run, I produce this error:

```
python(66449,0x105ea3dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x1071c3b60: pointer being freed was not allocated
python(66449,0x105ea3dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I have tried using the require-archs=intel, but this errors out, and it appears that I only have single architecture files: Non-fat file: /usr/bin/python is architecture: x86_64

### thank you,

Comment: Good question. It may help your chance of getting a useful answer to (1) create a mini-repository that can easily reproduce this issue and/or (2) [filing an issue at delocate](https://github.com/matthew-brett/delocate/issues)